# Swift clear camera preview layer

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I have an app that displays camera preview on AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.
When app goes to background session is stopped. The problem is, that when I open the app again, then before new session is initialized, there is sill a preview from the time I stopped the session on the layer. How can I clean this preview on AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer? I wan't it to contain just black background until new session is working.

Some parts of the code are bellow, but not all of it:

```
private var displayVideo = false {
    didSet {
        guard displayVideo != oldValue else { return }
        if displayVideo {
            // Configure video capture session.
            captureSession = {
                guard let captureDevice = self.captureDevice else { return nil }
                let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
                captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
                let videoDeviceInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
                guard captureSession.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) else {
                    print("Warning. Failed to add input to capture session.")
                    return nil
                }
                captureSession.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
                configureVideoDevice()
                return captureSession
            }()
            configureVideoOrientation()
        }
        else { captureSession = nil }
    }
}

private var captureSession: AVCaptureSession? {
    didSet {
        if oldValue != captureSession { oldValue?.stopRunning() }
        cameraPreviewLayer.session = captureSession
        captureSession?.startRunning()
    }
}
private lazy var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice? = {
    guard let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else {
        print("Warning. Failed to get capture device.")
        return nil
    }
    return videoDevice
}()
private lazy var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = {
    let layer = self.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    return layer
}()
```

Comment: For this you can assign nil to preview layer when you stop the session on the layer.

Comment: I can't assign nil to preview layer in this situation, because I'm using self.layer casted to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in UIView subclass. Is there another way? I would like not to add separate layer just for this.

Comment: you can create new later and add to the layer --- and also as you are working on camera ....may be this third party will help you : https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder ....check this....hope it will u

Comment: Before casting the self.layer, you can changes the background color of the self.layer for the stopped session to show the black background.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following solution. The idea is to hide preview layer when a capture session is stopped and preview layer's superview should have black background color.

```
func startSession() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        // Need to start the session in the background thread.
        // Otherwise runtime warning will be displayed.
        captureSession?.startRunning()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            previewLayer.hidden = false
        }
    }
}

func stopSession() {
    captureSession?.stopRunning()
    previewLayer.hidden = true
}
```